# Can't move multi-value (embedded) fields in Tridion GUI

Tags: cme, 2011-sp1, embedded-items

Strange thing has happened on out Tridion 2011 SP1 fresh installation (with HR2).
We are not able to move multi-value (embedded) fields anymore inside the Tridion CME GUI.

I checked out all the Hotfixes to see if one could have broken it, or one addresses the issue, but I didn't find any. Before I start undoing hotfixes I was wondering if anyone has had this issue before, and of course if you were able to solve it.

It is not working in any of the recommended browsers (Chrome, Firefox IE9)

EDIT: Added a link to a Youtube screencast to illustrate issue: http://youtu.be/6ZAjilkamHA

Comment: "We are not able to move..." Why is that? Are the buttons not shown? Or do they show, but don't do anything when you click them? If the latter, are there any error messages on your browser's JavaScript console when you click the buttons?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately for me the problem wasn't really there.
As the included screencast shows it actually was working, but I/we didn't "get it".

At first it looks like it isn't working, because I expected to be able select it (by clicking on it) and to drag it in a different position, just like in the older Tridion versions.

But, now it turns out that it is a two click action. First you select the item you want to move (button looks visually pressed as well), then you select the new position in the green highlighted area and let go when it turns dark green. Extra confusion is added when you select all the text and labels, and it looks like it is not working.

I would have deleted the question, but was unable to, so perhaps it might help someone who encounters the same issue. For me, as somewhat of a Tridion veteran this does not look and feel very intuitive... But, it works!

Answer (score 2):

As @Frank mentioned in his comment, please explain the issue being more specific.

But the first thing you should do is, check the browser settings according to the link below:

[Configuring your Web browser for Content Manager Explorer](http://docs.sdl.com/LiveContent/content/en-US/SDL_Tridion_2011_SPONE/task_43B1609144D94562A394BB51FAC884B9) (Login Required)

you can also find it in the user manual doc.